# How to link Excel to Acces when the files are saved on sharepoint, then refresh in Excel service

Tags: excel, access, refresh

We have files in excel that are saved on sharepoint.  We want to pull this into access, but when trying to link to them from access, we get a an error that they must be XML files.  How can i link these?

Also, i then am point pivot tables at this access queruy and then display using Excel Services.  Will this refresh when the page opens?